# Quantile normal and lognormal

Tags: probability, distribution, itos-lemma, normal-distribution, lognormal

Let's assume we have a normal distribution $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. In a normal distribution the quantile can be calculated as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_X ^{-1}(p)=\mu +\sigma {\sqrt {2}}\operatorname {erf} ^{-1}(2p-1)
\end{equation}

If we want to calculate the value in the future of a stock we map it as:

\begin{equation}
Y=\exp(X)
\end{equation}
Which means:
\begin{equation}
\log(Y)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}

I would like to know that if the function of the quantile can be calculated based directly on:

\begin{equation}
\Phi_Y ^{-1}(p)=\exp(\mu -\sigma/2+\sigma {\sqrt {2}}\operatorname {erf} ^{-1}(2p-1))
\end{equation}

The part of the equation $-\sigma/2$ is extracted from îto calculus, however, I cannot find anywhere the correctness of this equation (I deduced it). I think the function $exp$ is monotonic, so, it should preserve the value for the quantiles, but I'm not certain. One of my certainties is that $\mu$ changed to $\mu-\sigma/2$, I have no idea if that modifies in some way the calculation of $\Phi_Y ^{-1}(p)$, or if $\sigma$ also changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quantiles are preserved under monotonic transformations, hence the quantile for $Y$ is simply the exponential of the quantile of $X$, no need for corrections whatsoever (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159460/can-quantiles-be-calculated-for-lognormal-distributions) for instance).

Put otherwise, let $q$ denote the quantile $\alpha$ of $X$ i.e.
$$\Bbb{P}(X \leq q) = \alpha$$ 
then
\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}( X \leq q ) &= \Bbb{P}( \underbrace{\exp(X)}_{Y} \leq \underbrace{\exp(q)}_{Q} ) = \alpha 
\end{align}

Comment: However, I still have a question. Based on îtos lemma, the mean was transformed to $\mu-\sigma/2$ doesn't it affect anything? I mean, if the mean changed, shouldn't the variance also? (btw, nice the demonstration of your last equation, that makes me understand more)

Comment: Mean does change, but variance (and the other higher moments) as well. All in all in does not affect anything.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly. I mean that in order to keep the mean from the normal to the exponential, your mean becomes $\mu-\sigma/2$, but I do not know if that's the same case for volatility (since it is one of the parameters for the quantile). In any case, I was just trying with a montecarlo empirical quantile in time to see how these analytical quantiles behave (image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0rl5.png). I did the test to verify if the volatility changes as input, and it apparently works. Sorry for not accepting the answer before, I wanted to verify that. =)