# Quantile with periodic investing

Tags: monte-carlo, probability, distribution, normal-distribution, lognormal

## Short Version

Can I get a quantile of such an expression?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} A_k\exp(\mathcal{N}(t_k\mu-\sigma\sqrt{t_k}/2,\sigma)))
\end{equation}

I know I can do it for one part of the summation as stated [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/quantile-normal-and-lognormal), however I would like to know if that can be also the case for the summation.

## Long Version

Let's say I have a periodic investment, in a really simplified case, we have the user deposits $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ as in the following image.

[image]

The deposits $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ happen at $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$ respectively, being the period of time between each transaction $t$. The return of the period of time $t$ is $\mu$ and the volatility is $\sigma$.I want to know how much I have at time $t_3$ with a probability of $90\%$.

My variables are normally random distributed. This means that for example in order to project $A_1$ to the times $t_1$, $t_2$ and $t_3$ we will have the following equations:

\begin{equation}
X_{A_1,t_1}\sim A_1\exp(\mathcal{N}(0t\mu-\sigma\sqrt{0t}/2,0\sigma))=A_1\\
X_{A_1,t_2}\sim A_1\exp(\mathcal{N}(t\mu-\sigma\sqrt{1t}/2,\sigma\sqrt{t}))\\
X_{A_1,t_3}\sim A_1\exp(\mathcal{N}(2t\mu-\sigma\sqrt{2t}/2,\sigma\sqrt{2t}))
\end{equation}

In the first equation you have exactly the same money because your deposit was it $t_1$, the same time that we analyze. Now, we know that we can calculate a quantile for a normal distribution is $\Phi^{-1}_P=\mu+\sqrt{2}\sigma \operatorname {erf} ^{-1}(2P-1)$ where $P \in [0,1]$, in our case $.9$ because we want to verify $90\%$ and $\operatorname {erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Thus, we can calculate the quantile of $A_1$ in $t_3$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Phi^{-1}_{A_1,t_3|P}= A_1\exp(2t\mu-\sigma\sqrt{2t}/2+\sqrt{2}\sigma\sqrt{2t} \operatorname {erf} ^{-1}(2P-1))
\end{equation}

Some reference to this equation [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/quantile-normal-and-lognormal). My question is, can I sum all the values of the quantiles to $t_3$? or, how can I obtain the values of the quantiles at $t_3$?

I tried the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\Phi^{-1}_{t_3|P}=\Phi^{-1}_{A_1,t_3|P}+\Phi^{-1}_{A_2,t_3|P}+\Phi^{-1}_{A_3,t_3|P}
\end{equation}

As shown before, the last term of the quation is just $A_3$ but the others depend on the time and the quantile. This equation is not right, I have some dissimilarities with a montecarlo simulation I did to verify the results.

I'm almost certain I must not sum quantiles the way I did, but I cannot find the proper resource to verify the equations.

Comment: Since you have put some effort in this question I'll answer it although it appears to me as "too basic" for this site, no offense meant.

Comment: no offense taken, I'm new, I want to learn =)

Answer (score 2):

The random variable
$$X = \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_k\exp(\mathcal{N}(t_k\mu-\sigma\sqrt{t_k}/2,\sigma)))$$ emerges as a weighted sum of individual random variables that are log-normally distributed.

Unfortunately, even if we assume that the individual r.v. involved in the sum are independent, a sum of log-normals (here $X$) possesses no analytically tractable probability density function.

You will therefore not be able to find a closed-form expression for the quantiles of $X$.

A practical solution however could be to use a "Monte Carlo" simulation in the loose sense: draw a (sufficient) number $M$ of random samples from $X$, $(x_i)_{i=1,...,M}$; sort them in ascending order and infer the desired quantile

These related questions ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134976/compute-quantile-of-sum-of-distributions-from-particular-quantiles) and [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281129/finding-the-distribution-of-sum-of-lognormal-random-variables)) may also help I guess.

Comment: thanks, both links are interesting, i'll check it out, I'm solving it with montecarlo, but I wanted an analytical solution to speed up the process